# Is there a way to run a function at the same time as rendering an .ejs file into an .html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I want to perform the function with page rendering.

The function loads a external JS file dynamically.

Thanks you.

Comment: I want to have chicken for dinner. Thank You. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Of course without specifying what do you want the function to do and how or even if it's on the client side or server side it's impossible to give you any more specific answer. But a correct answer to your question is: yes.